# How to set different paths for view helpers?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm developing a modular application with Zend Framework and I find that I use a lot of view helpers that are common across all my modules, I would like to have the following structure work, where I have a central location of view helpers to use in any module plus each module having its own view helpers, is this possible?

```
APPLICATION_PATH
    /modules/module1/views/helpers
    /modules/module2/views/helpers
    /modules/module3/views/helpers
    /views/helpers <-- central location for all modules
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you joellord for your help, based on the information given by joellord I was able to load view helpers from a central location plus the view helpers located in each of my modules. I added the following to my main application bootstrap file:

```
public function _initView(){
    $view = new Zend_View($this->getOptions());


    $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/helpers/', 'Application_Helpers_');
     $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
        'ViewRenderer'
    );
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, of course, I forgot to declare the view first.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In my Bootstrap, I have the following function:

```
protected function _initView() {
  $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/../library/Myapp/View/Helper/", 'Myapp_View_Helper_');
  }
```

That helps me achieve what I think you want.  My general helpers are all located in /library/Myapp/View/Helper